# Help in solving $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-e^x+\cos 2x}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

The question is

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-e^x+\cos 2x}{x^2}$$

 I tried solving it
as follows

My method
[image: My method]

 My answer is $-2$ but actual answer is $-5/2$ so where is my method wrong?

Comment: Please type up your method using MathJax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers given above are all giving methods to solve the problem. But this is to tell you where you went wrong in your approach.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-e^x+\cos 2x}{x^2}&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-e^x+1+\cos 2x-1}{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-e^x+1-2\sin^2 x}{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-e^x+1}{x^2}-2\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\\
&=\color{red}{\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}-\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x^2}}-2\\
\end{align*}
This  highlighted step is where you went wrong. The limit of $1/x$ doesn't exist and you split the second term as $\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{e^x-1}{x}\right)$ and then just took the limit of only the parenthetical term which again is incorrect because when you take $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)g(x)$, then for this to be $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \, \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$, you need both limits should exist, whereas here $\lim_{x \to 0} 1/x$ doesn't.

Comment: Infact if $x\to 0^+$ I have $\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{e^x-1}{x}\right)\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

With the l'Hopital (applied twice) you have:
$$\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{x-e^x+\cos \left(2x\right)}{x^2}\right)=\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{1-e^x-2\sin \left(2x\right)}{2x}\right)=\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{-e^x-4\cos \left(2x\right)}{2}\right)=-\frac 52$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the question is where i got my method wrong , which concept, theory or calculation i got wrong

Comment: @Pratham What is $x=(0+h)$?

Answer (score 1):

In your second to last line, you are too hasty to cancel terms. The correct approach is
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h-e^h+1}{h^2}-\frac{2\sin(h)^2}{h^2}
$$Use the asymptotic $e^h\approx 1+ h +h^2/2+O(h^3)$ and you'll be on the right track.
$$
=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h+1-(1+h+h^2/2+O(h^3))}{h^2}-\frac{2\sin(h)^2}{h^2}=\frac{-1}{2}-2=\frac{-5}{2}
$$